# Use NSMutableData but appendData failed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutabledata

When I init NSMutableData with 100 length,it append data failed.

```
self.receiveData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:100];
if (nil == self.receiveData) {
    MYLOG;
    return NO;
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)aConn didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.receiveData appendData:data];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.receiveData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",string);//there can't log any string
    MYLOG;
    [string release];
}
```

But when I init with 0 length,it can append well

```
self.receiveData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
if (nil == self.receiveData) {
    MYLOG;
    return NO;
}
```

I'm new to Objective-C, can you help me with that ?

Answer (score 3):

There's a difference between `initWithLength:` and `initWithCapacity:`. `initWithLength:` actually gives you that many bytes of 0s at the beginning of the data, while `initWithCapacity:` is just a hint for storage purposes. If you try to make a string out of data with 0s at the beginning, it will be an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

use [**initWithCapacity:**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/Reference/NSMutableData.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableData/initWithCapacity%3a) and here you are leaking with memory leak, if you have  declared `receiveData` as `retain` in your property.

```
self.receiveData = [[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:0] autorelease];
```

OR

```
 NSMutableData * myData =  [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
   self.receiveData = myData ;
   [myData release];
    myData  = nil ;
```

Comment: @Gin: you could keep data instance as `retain` and use the solution suggested in my answer,And also not forget to release your data instance in `dealloc` function if you keep that as `retain`.

Comment: Ok,I'll follow your suggested,but I want know why retain is better than assign,thank you,Jhaliya.

Comment: @Gin : It's solely depend on How you are going to use `instance variable` in your class. it's hard to say which is better than other ..

Answer (score 1):

Try `-initWithCapacity:` or `+dataWithCapacity:` instead. `-initWithLength:` creates a data object containing the number of bytes that you specify. So, when you append data to your mutable data object, you get an object containing 100 bytes of zero, followed by whatever data you appended. It's likely that NSString looks at that first zero byte and returns an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I Just did it this way:

```
self.globalData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init]; 

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.globalData appendData:data];
    float progress = (float)[self.globalData length] / self.downloadSize;
    self.threadProgressView.progress = progress;
}
```

And it works pretty well, give it a try...